# Matching string to text in static resource text file

Tags: apex, static-resources, string

I have a text file in static resources of banned passwords (list contains values such as 'password1234', 'qwertyuiop' etc).

When comparing values in list with input pw string, they fail to match.

Code I'm testing in dev console:

```
String pass = 'password1234';
StaticResource sr = [SELECT body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'BannedPW'];
String bannedList = sr.body.toString(); 
for(String bannedVal : bannedList.split('\n')) {
    if (bannedVal == pass) {
        system.debug(bannedVal + ' = ' + pass);
    }
    else {
        system.debug('No match: ' + bannedVal);
    }
}
```

Little lost as to why they fail to match.

Comment: Did you try to add a `System.debug(bannedVal);` statement at the start of your `for` loop to check which value is returned?

Comment: @MartinLezer Yes, each line from the static resource file is returned 'USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|password0123', 'USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|password1234' etc

Comment: There are maybe some leading or trailing white space characters. Try to replace your if statement with: `if (bannedVal.trim() == pass) {`. The trim function removes theses characters.

Comment: @MartinLezer You're right, that worked (wonder why the whitespace was being added though...). Could you put that as the answer so I can mark it. Thanks

Comment: My guess is that the lines of your file are separated using these characters `'\r\n',` not only `'\n'.` You can check this by using `bannedList.split('\r\n')` and removing the `trim` method. It might work too. But the use of the `trim` method is a better solution.

Comment: @MartinLezer Yup, it is using '\r\n'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in your static resource file might be surrounded by leading or trailing white space characters.

The `trim()` method of the [`String`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) class can remove these characters.

Then, you have to replace your `if` statement by:

```
if (bannedVal.trim() == pass) {
```